# jQuery data method returns integer instead of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-droppable" data-number="P"></div>
```

**JS Source Inspection**

```
div.ui-droppable
|...
|--attributes:NamedNodeMap
|  |...
|  |--data-number
|  |  |...
|  |  |--nodeValue: "P"
|  |  |...
|  |  |--textContent: "P"
|  |  |--value: "P"
|  |  |...
|  |...
|
|--dataset:DOMStringMap
|  |
|  |--number: "P"
   |...
```

**jQuery**

But

```
$(this).data('number');
```

gives me integer **1**. How can I get the **P** using `data` method?

Comment: `this` is the `div`. I think I have clearly stated that in question body

Comment: Where is this `$(this).data('number');`? It seems to work this way: [codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielsiedler/p1amvzmo/)

Comment: @Trix did You checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You did not bind data.
You can access that data-number by:

```
$(this).attr('data-number');
```

Comment: I know that, but I want to find out whats the problem with `data` method and the question title and body clearly states that, so this is not gonna be an answer. thanks anyway